# converting the number to the required currency format

Tags: javascript

Customising the number to a currency format. See the below snippet. But when passing negative number i need to customise it.

```js
function getMoneyValue(number) {
  var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'INR'
  });

  return formatter.format(number)
}

console.log(getMoneyValue(200))
console.log(getMoneyValue(-200)) // expected [-] ₹200.00
```

So for customising referring [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/formatToParts) When i tried this snippet the problem is i am not getting the rupee symbol

```js
function getMoneyValue(number) {
  var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'INR'
  });
  let parts = formatter.formatToParts(number).map((part) => {
    switch (part.type) {
      case "currency":
        return number >= 0 ? number : `[-] ${Math.abs(number)}`;
      default:
        return part.value;
    }
  });
  return parts[1];
}

console.log(getMoneyValue(200)) // expected  ₹200.00
console.log(getMoneyValue(-200)) // expected [-] ₹200.00
```

Any help is appreciated, what is the better way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check should have been against the type **minusSign**. You don't need to add a check under integer type as only integer type is passed without the **-ve sign** which  be a positive integer value.

```js
function getMoneyValue(number) {
  var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'INR'
  });
  let parts = formatter.formatToParts(number).map(({type, value}) => {
    switch (type) {  
      case "integer":
        return value;
      case "minusSign":
        return '[-]'
      default:
        return value;
    }
  }).reduce((string, part) => string + part);
  return parts;
}

console.log(getMoneyValue(200))
console.log(getMoneyValue(-200))
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
  function getMoneyValue(number) {
  var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'INR'
   });
    
   if(number < 0) {
      return '[-] '+ formatter.format(Math.abs(number))
    }
   
   return formatter.format(number)
  }

console.log(getMoneyValue(200))
console.log(getMoneyValue(-200))
```